# Change list index of jstl variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

When the user is redirected to a page an attribute for the session is set with a list from the server...

```
           List<Card> usersCards = DataDAO.getCardsForUser(userAccount);
           if(usersCards == null) {
               throw new IOException("Card could not be retrieved for this user");
           }
           session.setAttribute("usersCards",usersCards);

           //After successfully logging in send them to the Question page
           RequestDispatcher dispatch = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/QuestionPage.jsp");
           dispatch.forward(request,response);
```

I hold that list in a jstl variable...

```
<c:set var="cardlist" scope="session" value="${sessionScope.usersCards}"></c:set>
    <c:set var="cardIndex" scope="session" value="0"></c:set>
```

on the click of an html button I want to go to the next index of this list. I thought this could be accomplished with JavaScript, one poster recommended using a hidden value holder on the jsp page like this:

```
<div id="questionCounter">${cardIndex}</div>
```

then when I get to my javascript click function I am stuck and confused on the syntax. I simply want to hold the value of this counter, increment it with each button click then update the value of text area to the current index of that list....

```
$("#next").click(function() {
       var questions = '${cardlist}';
       var index = $('#questionCounter').html();
       index++;
       // here is where I'm stuck...


       $('#cardArea').val(questions[index]);
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this with ajax in case anyone else gets confused:

```
$( "#next" ).click(function(){
       $.get("QuestionPage", function(responseJSON){

           //set the question and category texts
           $("#cardArea").val(responseJSON["card"]);
           $( "#cat"  ).text(responseJSON["category"]);
           $( "#cardid" ).text(responseJSON["flashCardnum"]);

           //clear answer field after every 'next'...
           $( "#answerArea" ).val("");

           //set the click function of show button to show the answer..
           $( "#show" ).click(function() {
                $( "#answerArea" ).val(responseJSON["answer"]); 
            });
       });

   });
```

doGet() in the servlet:

```
//get which user is associated with this browser session...
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String sessID = session.getId();
        UserAccount user = activeUsers.get(sessID);

        //get the users cards that are stored within that user object...
        List<Card> cards = user.getAllCards();
        System.out.println("user "+user.getFirstname()+"has "+cards.size()+" cards.");

        //Use the current count to get the right card THEN increment it...
        Integer currentCount = (Integer)session.getAttribute("cardCount");
        System.out.println("Card Count in doGet(): "+currentCount);
        //check that you are not out of cards... if so take them from the top
        if(currentCount == (cards.size() - 1)){
            currentCount = 0;
        }

        // get the next card 
        Card nextCard = cards.get(currentCount);
        System.out.println("Next Card: "+nextCard.getCard());

        //increment and reset the session attribute...
        currentCount++;
        session.setAttribute("cardCount", currentCount);

        //encode next question as JSON
        String json = new Gson().toJson(nextCard);
        System.out.println("json coming in ajax: "+json);

        //write the next card to the response to be gotten by ajax...
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
```